# Views Grouping Pagination

Tags: views, paging

Using a view to display links to nodes sorted into categories (using grouped field on taxonomy) it's working great, however there is upwards of 20 nodes per term and I would only like to show 5 at a time. Ultimately an ajax *load more* on each of the terms is what I'm after, but a simple *ajax pagination* would work fine also.

Obviously standard pagination doesn't work for this use case as its paging all of the results where I want to add pagination to each of the terms.

I have been messing with `views_limit_grouping`, which could be a reasonable base to work from.

Another idea would be to create an individual views for each of the terms and insert them however with upwards of 30 terms creates a very messy views setup.

Appreciate any and all insights.

Comment: Did you since found some working solution to your problem? I'm really interested in a solution as well.